# Using Green's theorem to reduce the integral

Tags: calculus

Let S be the region of the plain bounded by the graph of $x^2$-$y^2$=4 and the lines y=2 and y=-2 and F(x,y)=($\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$,$\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$). Use Green's theorem to reduce the line integral $\iint_{dS}$F dx to the integral over a simpler curve, then using this technique evaluate the line integral.

But then I found out $\frac{dF_2}{dx_1}$=$\frac{dF_1}{dx_2}$,so how can I apply the Green's theorem, it will become $\iint_S$0 dA...

Comment: First check whether the function $F(x,\ y)$ satisfies the conditions of Green's theorem.

Comment: I presume you mean the line integral $\oint_{\partial S} \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf x$?

Answer (score 1):

Break up the curve into a combination of the original curve, the unit circle in reverse, and the connection between those 2 curves.
Then you can apply Green to that combined curve.

Comment: can you explain to me why the condition of Green's failed ? How can I determine whether the curve is positive oriented or not?

Comment: The condition for Green is that F has continuous partial derivatives on the entire region. By convention a closed curve is positively oriented if it runs counterclockwise.